# How to replace a specific data according to lines not by string? Python, Files

Tags: python, file, replace

```
import linecache


f = open("database.txt" , "r+")
password = input("What is your password? ")
for loop in range(3):
  line = f.readline()
  data = line.split(",")
  if data[1] == password:
    print(data[1])   #These are too help me understand the code
    print(data[0])
    b = data[0]
    newpass = "Hi"
    a = data[1]


    line1 = linecache.getline("database.txt" ,loop+1)
    print(line)
    print("Password Valid\n")
    write = (line1.replace(a, newpass)) 
    write = f.write(line1.replace(a, newpass))

f.close()
```

I have a file which stores data separated by columns. Each new line is a different users data:

1. username,password,Recovery1,Answer1,Recovery2,Answer2,Recovery3,Answer3,Recovery4,Answer4,
2. Recovery5,Answer5,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
3. happy,bye,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
4. bye,happy,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,

THIS IS THE WANTED FILE:

1. username,password,Recovery1,Answer1,Recovery2,Answer2,Recovery3,Answer3,Recovery4,Answer4,
2. Recovery5,Answer5,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
3. happy,Hi,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,
4. bye,happy,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,

I want the user to enter their password and then be able to change it. Which is the second column (e.g. data[1]). The program should then change the users password to a different one. "Hi" in this case. However, IT MUST NOT AFFECT ANOTHER USERS USERNAME AS THE PASSWORDS AND USERNAMES COULD BE THE SAME. EG. changing bye to HI in third line, should not change bye in the fourth line to Hi.
The code can append the new line, but the previous line still exists. Is this the write way to go about it? Could you help? The code should be able to change other lines password according to the users input.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reading all lines into memory and then splitting the lines at the commas (e.g., `fields = line.split(',')`). After that, you can use the position to change the field, like `fields[1] = newpassword`. Don't try to match the string value of the old password, because that will lead to the problems that you have pointed out.
(I hope you are implementing this only as an exercise. For real world applications you should almost never write this kind of code yourself)

Comment: @maxdebayser Yes, its an exercise. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @maxdebayser Sorry, but I've tried this code and it doesn't change it in the file 
`import linecache


f = open("database.txt" , "r+")
newpassword = "NEW"
for loop in range(3):
  line = f.readline()
  data = line.split(",")
  if data[1] == "bye":
    print(data[1])
    data[1] = newpassword
  

f.close()`